# Splitting a multi-lingual string

Tags: c#, java, .net

I have an AS/400 reply text which comes multi-lingual string as shown below and is of 28872 characters length.

2012021920120219000000000300000D000000010146208D22ﻑﻳﺭﺎﺻﻣ

I have to split the text 240 characters per block but as I have arabic characters in between my logic is failing to extract the exact 240 character length.

My question is how to split a multi-lingual text with out loosing the original format?

Answer (score 4):

You should write your code that way that it, depending on the text encoding, extracts exactly 240 characters. A character can take several bytes depending on the encoding. A common encoding is `UTF-8`. Take a look at Wikipedia on how UTF-8 works. This will allow you to write correct working code. [UTF-8 Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

So, you should find out how many bytes the current character takes.

Of course, before you start off, make sure you know the encoding of the input text.

---

Know that Java uses UTF-16 to store characters. So, this means that an arabic character can be made out of more than one `char`, because the code point exceeds 2^16. To work with this correctly, I would convert the whole string to a byte buffer:

```
String longStringToSplit = ...;
byte[] stringUTF8 = longStringToSplit.getBytes("UTF-8");
// now, split it manually and correct, using the utf-8 specifications you
// can find in the link I gave you to wiki.
```

Comment: The text which i have is of UTF-8 format. When i split it 240 characters each, the values are getting misplaced. I think Arabic has something to do with this..

Comment: But that is because you are splitting the bytes in the middle of a character. You should split on characters. To do that, you should find out how long a char is.

Comment: Can you help me on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code can do this:

```
List<string> SplitString(String input, int length)
{
    var splitedList = new List<string>();

    string block = "";
    var arabicBlock = "";

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (block.Length + arabicBlock.Length > length - 1)
        {
            splitedList.Add(block);
            block = "";
        }

        var b = (int) c;
        // check here if charachter is arabic
        // this is a sample, or you can use 'IsArabicChar'
        //if (b > 6000)
        if(IsArabicChar(c))
        {
            arabicBlock += c.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            block += arabicBlock + c;
            arabicBlock = "";
        }
    }
    return splitedList;
}
```

`IsArabicChar` method can be useful:

```
internal static bool IsArabicChar(Char character)
{
    if (character >= 0x600 && character <= 0x6ff)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0x750 && character <= 0x77f)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0xfb50 && character <= 0xfc3f)
        return true;

    if (character >= 0xfe70 && character <= 0xfefc)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```